Prize pool reward
Someone contacted with me through WhatsApp then after 2 weeks she showed me and introduced me to smart contract I’ve done some research about it she then told me I can do this and start earning some profits too she sent me a link and showed me how to activate the smart contract after that she said we can get rewards by depositing around 5000 or higher usdt

This is a scam. There is no such thing as depositing to "activate" a smart contract. If you send the 5000 USDT you will not be getting it back.
